# Cannot connect through RDP while session is in progress

Tags: windows, networking, ssh, remote-desktop, windows-server-2012

I've recently ran into:

[image: RDP]

when trying to log into a (win 2016)server but I know there is no one else logged in; the only

possibility being (I'm guessing) that  I installed a virtual machine on vbox Yesterday that has a bridged

adapter; I can still SSH into it.

Can it be that the connection timed out but wasn't registered as closed on the server? I can't do much

(e.g. restart RDP) from the virtual machine. How can I end the remote session?

Comment: I see you already solved it, next time, login to console and it will work. To do that, start remote desktop as normally, but in the addressbar, at the end, enter /admin. For example: `myserver:3389 /admin`